# Oracle SQL add new column based on value of other column

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, substring, string-concatenation

I'm looking for some help to create a new column based on values from another column - if this is even possible... This is not an ideal solution but I'm out running out of options.

I need to replace the beginning folder paths, change the direction of the \ and change the extension

```
Existing Field:

\\BRRNAKCL12\Audiofiles22\1Year\Diogarfngal_ZZZZZZZZZ\2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572.cca

New Field:

/location/TELEDATA/2020/Aug/03/5249013/5249013-07-25-18-96572.wav
```

Oracle version Version 19.2.1.247

Thank you in advance

Comment: What would be the pattern of the path you want to extract?  Do you need the string after 2020?

Comment: This is the string I need to extract 2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572

Comment: The path is always /location/TELEDATA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column to your table named NewField:

```
Alter table TableName add NewField varchar(500);
```

Then update NewField by replacing some characters as you wish from ExistingField.

```
update TableName set NewField= replace(replace(existingfield,'\','/'),'.cca','.wav')
```

Here I have just replace '' with '/' and '.cca' with '.wav'.

To replace path also:

```
update TableName set NewField= '/location/TELEDATA/'||substr(replace(replace(existingfield,'\','/'),'.cca','.wav'),instr(replace(replace(existingfield,'\','/'),'.cca','.wav'),'/2020',1,1) + 1)
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable (existingfield varchar(500));

 insert into mytable values('
 \\BRRNAKCL12\Audiofiles22\1Year\Diogarfngal_ZZZZZZZZZ\2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572.cca');
```

Add new column:

```
 Alter table mytable add NewField varchar(500);
```

Update query:

```
 update mytable set NewField= '/location/TELEDATA/'||substr(replace(replace(existingfield,'\','/'),'.cca','.wav'),instr(replace(replace(existingfield,'\','/'),'.cca','.wav'),'/2020',1,1) + 1)
```

Select query:

```
 select * from mytable;
```

Output:

| EXISTINGFIELD | NEWFIELD |
| --- | --- |
| \BRRNAKCL12\Audiofiles22\1Year\Diogarfngal_ZZZZZZZZZ\2020\Aug\03\5249013\5249013-07-25-18-96572.cca | /location/TELEDATA/2020/Aug/03/5249013/5249013-07-25-18-96572.wav |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19b857f92ca56acf690e02ffff9291c2)*

Comment: Thank you - the new path will always be /location/TELEDATA/

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Can you modify your answer? At the end of your instr you have '/2020',1,1) + 1)... however the year won't always be 2020 so I don't need that as a static value. There are several years of data so that is part of the pattern I want to extract. I believe it should be ,1,1,1) + 1) ???

Comment: My idea didn't work... I look forward to your response.

Comment: Is there any range of years? Is Diogarfngal_ZZZZZZZZZ static?

Comment: I figured it out 'Diogarfngal_ZZZZZZZZZ',1,1)+22 This way the pattern extracted starts with the year folder. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's great. Congrates! Best wishes.